# I renamed my repository and I am having trouble updating my files

Tags: github, repository, rename

Terminal screenshot of The error I am getting:

[image: Terminal screenshot of The error I am getting]

I updated the name of my repository on git hub after I had already pulled everything onto my local drive. I now am having trouble updating my local drive with the changes.

when I enter the command:

```
> git push origin master
```

I get the following error:

```
> error: src refspec master does not match any

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ktrudickm/Classwork.git'
```

I am relatively new to this so this may be an easy fix but I am sort of stuck.

Comment: You probably never updated the repo url which you can do with `git remote set-url ...`. See the [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-repository)

Answer (score 0):

The repository info is hidden in the `.git` folder of your project. Open `.git/config` and edit the url to match the new repository.